# add googlemap.bundle to project cause xcode5 halt

Tags: ios, iphone, google-maps, xcode5, google-maps-sdk-ios

When I drag

> googlemap.bundle

to project or add with cocoapods cause xcode5 halt and don't work but xcode is ok with

> googlemap.framework

what should I do ?

Answer (score 1):

You dont even need to add `googlemap.bundle` by dragging and dropping like the Google Documentation suggests. Simply drag the `googlemap.framework` to your project, then go to your project's Build Settings and under "Framework Search Paths" add `$(SRCROOT)` and all should work fine.

Comment: This is what I did: Drag and drop `googlemap.framework` to project. (Make sure "Copy items into destination group's folder" is checked.)

Comment: recursive or non-recursive? @Mepla

Comment: This is what I did: Drag and drop `googlemap.framework` to project. (Make sure "Copy items into destination group's folder" is checked.) Then go to Project's Build Settings. Search "Framework", under "Framework Search Paths" (Which you probably already have something like /Users/Pooyak/"Project Name", add the + button and then add `$(SRCROOT)`. That did it for me. Also, if you dont do this and add the bundle like the google document says, it will become a pain in the neck when using any kind of source control. Non-Recursive would do fine, cause SRCROOT doesnt have any parent that matters to us